# ValidateLength - No maximum length

Tags: powershell

When validating the length of a string parameter:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[ValidateLength(6,128)]
[string]$value
```

Is it possible to not enforce a *maximum* length (only minimum)? I tried:

```
[ValidateLength(6,0)]
```

But this produces a runtime error.

Comment: 1) Use a really, really long maximum length. 2) Use `[ValidatePattern('.{6}.*')]`. (The error isn't as pretty, though.) 3) Use `[ValidateScript({$_.Length -gt 5})]` (same issue with ugliness of error, though.) 4) Check for a minimum length in the function rather than in the parameter attribute, and throw an error if too short (i.e., check the length at runtime).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>It's not possible using that attribute directly.</s>

The parameters of that attributes are `[int]`s so implicitly the maximum you could set is `[int]::MaxValue` .

<s>, but you can't use that expression directly because you need a literal.</s>

So, you could hard code the value of `[int]::MaxValue` but `[int]` could technically be different sizes on different platforms (then again, a 2 GB string might not even work so hard coding 2147483647 may not be the worst thing).

I had a typo in my test script and thought it wasn't possible to use `[int]::MaxValue` directly, but it turns out that's not true (thanks Mathias for making me go back and check it again):

```
[ValidateLength(6, [int]::MaxValue)]
```

I tested on version 5.1, but it seems this may not work in v2, and I'm not sure when exactly support was added.

---

Another possibility is to validate with a script:

```
[ValidateScript( { $_.Length -ge 6 } )]
```

If you want a better error message, there's always the `throw` trick:

```
[ValidateScript( { $_.Length -ge 6 -or $(throw [System.ArgumentException]"String must be at least 6 characters") } )]
```

Also, as suggested by Bill and Ansgars, you can validate with a regex:

```
[ValidatePattern('^.{6,}$')]
```

Comment: `[ValidateLength(6, [int]::MaxValue)]` worked fine when I just tested it, even when launching the script from outside PowerShell. Another alternative would be `[ValidatePattern('^.{6,}$')]`.

Comment: Or: Check the length at runtime and throw an error if too short. (Has the advantage of letting you write your own error message.)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I've added the regex check as well.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart and another alternative to for a better error message.

Comment: @briantist that works too (if you insist on parameter rather than runtime validation <grin>)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart like so many things, it depends on the situation, but I'd say I _usually_ do prefer parameter validation :)

Comment: `[int]::MaxValue` is a perfectly fine input value for the second argument to `ValidateLength`, doesn't have to be a literal value

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen not sure when it became valid, but it fails in v2.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen after going back and testing, you are correct. Edited.

Comment: For completeness, this works the same way with `[ValidateCount()]`.